Replace this USB power board
I have broken this board, its for USB powered lamp. I presume it is a power conditioner for usb power... As its before the light color/control board. Im not sure if it was USB or USB C - I presume its around a 5v output not 12 or more. Correct me if you can see im wrong...
Can someone reccomend a replacement board for this board please... Based off what is going on with this one (if possible) ... It needs to have terminals for a button


I'm not sure what It needs to have terminals for a button means. Can you edit the question to describe what the button needs to control?

It seems to be an "old" charger USB - BAT with micro-USB like this one

Now, it is a USB-C one like this one


Thanks for your repsonse... Someone tried to modify this lamp to be battery opperated. And botched it. I thought this board was appart of the original lamp electronics. I realised an hour after posting this that its probrably the charging board for the battery the guy tried to install. You have just confirmed this for me. I wont need to replace this but thanks for the confirmation.

@Wan33 next time, please update your question when you discover new information
